# How do I set the password with bitnami/cassandra:4.1 and Docker compose?

Tags: docker, cassandra, bitnami

I have the following docker-compose file...

```
version: "3.8"     
services:       
  cassandra:         
    container_name: cassandra         
    image: bitnami/cassandra:4.1                
    ports:           
      - "9042:9042"         
    environment:           
      - CASSANDRA_AUTHENTICATOR=PasswordAuthenticator           
      - CASSANDRA_USER=cassandra           
      - CASSANDRA_PASSWORD=password
```

When I run and exec I see that password correctly...

```
$ echo $CASSANDRA_PASSWORD
password
```

But when I try to connect I need to use cassandra/cassandra. What am I missing how do I change the password?

I also tried this which causes it to not authenticate at all and this also worked as expected...

```
 - CASSANDRA_AUTHENTICATOR=AllowAllAuthenticator
 - CASSANDRA_AUTHORIZER=AllowAllAuthorizer
```

So I know that at least some cassandra variables are working. So I can switch off and on the password check I just can't change the password used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed this `env`.

- `CASSANDRA_PASSWORD_SEEDER`: Password seeder will change the Apache
  Cassandra default credentials at initialization. In clusters, only
  one node should be marked as password seeder. Default: **no**

So, this your `docker-compose` file should be:

```
version: "3.8"         
services:           
  cassandra:             
    container_name: cassandra             
    image: bitnami/cassandra:4.1                    
    ports:               
      - "9042:9042"             
    environment:               
      - CASSANDRA_AUTHENTICATOR=PasswordAuthenticator               
      - CASSANDRA_USER=cassandra      
      - CASSANDRA_PASSWORD_SEEDER=yes         
      - CASSANDRA_PASSWORD=password
```

Comment: I think you should make a comment at the end to make sure to blow away the /bitnami/cassandra/data folder as well. The first time I tried without doing that it didn't work. I know I didn't include the volume but that was to help with simplicity of the question. In reality I was using a volume. Thank you!

Comment: Oh right, If you use `volume`, you must clear data in volume. Because that data use pasword of the previous deploy.